# UITableView setContentInset not working

Tags: ios, uitableview

I set a button action like this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
[tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(40, 0, 0, 0)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

But, the tableView doesn't move down if the `contentSize.height > tableView.frame.size.height`.
What is the solution?

Comment: make certain that "`tableView`" is not NULL...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try the below code:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
[tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(40, 0, 0, 0)];
[tableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 1) animated:YES];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

may this helps.

Comment: if this is the correct answer then mark as accepted so that others get the benefit from this.